# MAMP - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I'm totally confused here. I have MAMP on an iMac it says MySQL is running.
When I try access it via Sequel Pro I can connect using the socket option

[image]

However if I try to connect using the Standard method I get a 'connection refused'

[image: **enter image description here**]

[image]

When I try connect with PHP I get the connection refused message

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1:8889;dbname=wabie_centraldb", "root", "root", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET sql_mode=""') );
```

I'm confused because obviously mysql is running (because I can connect one way).

I have the same setup on my MacBook and it all works perfectly

Any suggestions?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard port for MySQL is 3306 and does not need to be specified in the connection:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=wabie_centraldb", "root", "root", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET sql_mode=""') );
```

To specify a database connection port use the following DSN string:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=wabie_centraldb", "root", "root", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET sql_mode=""') );
```

You can test 3306 in your Sequel Pro in your standard connection. In addition, you may have to change the host from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` depending on how you're set up.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I'm still getting the same error (PDO and Sequel Pro)

Comment: What port is your MySQL server running on? You may have to change 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Comment: That did it! Sequel Pro didn't like it but the php did

Thanks Jay - really appreciate it